# Apache not finding file from URL request

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, http, fedora, url

I'm trying to access a file from my localhost via

```
http://localhost/profile-pics/default.jpg
```

however apache keeps saying that the url doesn't exists 404. How can I configure apache to find my file? My directory is as follows ...

var/www/

profile-pics/
html/
cgi-bin/

I'm using Fedora

Comment: What does the config say where the `DocumentRoot` is? I guess it is rather `/var/www/html/` than `/var/www/` (or none of both).

Comment: The document root is DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the *DocumentRoot* is `/var/www/html`, you should move your `profile_pics` folder into it (`/var/www/html/profile_pics`). Simple as that.